# How to create C++ Desktop Application in JetBrains Rider

Tags: desktop-application, jetbrains-rider

**Is it possible to create C++ Desktop Application template in JetBrains Rider?**

---

How I can create Desktop Application with start files and C++ code like in Visual Studio?
[Visual Studio 2022 - project creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un8S6.png)

In Rider project creating menu I only find Library, Console app or Unit test.
[Rider 2023.1.2 - project creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1i41.png)

I try find plugins or target settings, but find nothing. Easy solution is to create project in Visual Studio and open it in Rider, but this is not as convenient as I created the project right away in the Rider.